# Why is it a syntax error to have an object attribute named "del", "return" etc?

Tags: python

I understand that one shouldn't be able to replace the behaviour of the "del" ("return" etc) keyword, but I do not understand why it is not possible to do this:

```
myobj.del(mystr)
```

What could the parser confuse it with? Is there a way to allow it?

Of course, I could use a different name, but I want to have a little custom wrapper around the AWS tool s3cmd and do things like `s3cmd.del("s3://some/bucket/")` and have the "del" handled by a `__getattr__` in my s3cmd class... so the name "del" is something I'd be really happy to manage to use.

Comment: There’s nothing magical about keywords. However, it makes parsers **vastly** easier to write when disallowing keywords for identifiers. In particular, it makes it easier to provide human-readable error messages for parse errors, because the parser is able to infer more context about the error.

Comment: You can still use `del` as an attribute, just not as an *identifier* (needed when accessing attributes). You can use `getattr(myobj, 'del')(mystr)`, but that's not nearly as convenient of course.

Comment: My goal is to have support for all the s3cmd ("s3cmd {put, get, del, ls etc}") in a nicely readable way. I guess using "delete" instead will be the next best option for me;

Comment: @KonradRudolph could you do a write-up of this comment? I feel the argument about making parsers easier is really what I was looking for, as I intended my question as a "philosophical" why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because such words are keywords. Keywords in Python are reserved words that cannot be used as ordinary identifiers.

The list includes [from the doc function `keyword`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html)

```
>>> import keyword  
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(keyword.kwlist)
['and',
 'as',
 'assert',
 'break',
 'class',
 'continue',
 'def',
 'del',
 'elif',
 'else',
 'except',
 'exec',
 'finally',
 'for',
 'from',
 'global',
 'if',
 'import',
 'in',
 'is',
 'lambda',
 'not',
 'or',
 'pass',
 'print',
 'raise',
 'return',
 'try',
 'while',
 'with',
 'yield']
```

The reason as to why is beautifully mentioned in [Konrad's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346945/why-is-it-a-syntax-error-to-have-an-object-attribute-named-del-return-etc/29346977#comment46879825_29346945)

> There’s nothing magical about keywords. However, it makes parsers **vastly** easier to write when disallowing keywords for identifiers. In particular, it makes it easier to provide human-readable error messages for parse errors, because the parser is able to infer more context about the error.