# Website to check Illegal variable names or keywords Python

Tags: python, variables

I may have stumbled on an illegal variable name

```
pass = "Pass the monkey!"
print pass
```

Syntax error: invalid syntax

I'm aware that some keywords are verboten as variables.
Is there the Pythonic equivalent to [JavaScript variable name validator](https://mothereff.in/js-variables)?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/29346945/4099593

Comment: There are so many related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864221/is-the-list-of-python-reserved-words-and-builtins-available-in-a-library; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595922/list-of-python-keywords; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642087/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-keywords-in-python

Comment: Python's compiler _is_ your "variable name validator" - as you just found out. Note that Python doesn't have that many keywords and that any half-decent code editor should identify and hilight them properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can test whether something is a keyword or not using the [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html) module

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword("pass")
True
>>> keyword.iskeyword("not_pass")
False
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html

> This module allows a Python program to determine if a string is a
>   keyword.
>
> **keyword.iskeyword(s)**
>
> Return true if s is a Python keyword.

Comment: You may also check built-in names: `dir(__builtins__)`

Answer (score 5):

Some variable names are illegal in Python because of it being a **reserved word.**

From the [`keywords` section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=keywords#keywords) in the Python docs:

> The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of
>   the language, **and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers.** They
>   must be spelled exactly as written here:

```
# Complete list of reserved words
and
del
from
not
while
as
elif      
global    
or        
with 
assert    
else      
if        
pass      
yield 
break     
except    
import    
print 
class     
exec      
in        
raise 
continue  
finally   
is        
return 
def       
for       
lambda  
try
True # Python 3 onwards
False # Python 3 onwards
None  # Python 3 onwards
nonlocal # Python 3 onwards
async # in Python 3.7
await # in Python 3.7
```

So, you cannot use any of the above identifiers as a variable name.

Comment: Coming new to a python 3.<strike>5</strike>7 near you there are two more: [`async` and `await`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/).

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: they'll become proper keywords in Python 3.7.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Thanks for the info. Updated the ans.

Comment: BTW, in Python 3, `None`, `True` and `False` are keywords too (this is a performance optimization trick).

Comment: Oh, and there's `nonlocal` too! :)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks. Updated the ans.

Answer (score 3):

This function will check if a name is a keyword in `Python` or one of Python built-in objects, which can be a [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), a [constant](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html), a [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) or an [exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) class.

```
import keyword
def is_keyword_or_builtin(name):
    return keyword.iskeyword(name) or name in dir(__builtins__)
```

While you can't use `Python keywords` as variable names, you are allowed to do it with `Python built-ins` though it's considered a bad practice so I will recommend to avoid it.

Comment: I'd add a note specifying that builtins names are not illegal variable names, though their usage is discouraged (for obvious reasons).

Comment: That's a good point, thanks @AndreaCorbellini.

Comment: Is that a python 3.x thing?    print keyword.iskeyword.iskeyword(pass) doesn't work "keyword" is not defined.

Comment: You need to import `keyword`.

Comment: Doh!  That's obvious now...